# Pandas styling: different colours for the same values in a df?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, styling

I'm trying to display dfs with a for loop in a jupyter notebook with background styling. However, there weird styling effects like the same value (0) in the df having different colors and the precision parameter not being followed. What am I doing wrong?

Code:

```py
for i in range(0,11):
    df = some_computation(data)
    df1 = pd.DataFrame()
    df1= df
    np.fill_diagonal(df1.values, 0) # for better contrast in my correlation values
    df1 = df1.style.background_gradient(cmap="RdBu_r").set_precision(4)
    display(df1)
```

Output:
[One example df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5GUr.png)

Quick addition: looks like these problems are occurring for all the dfs except the last one. The last df produced by the loop has the right colors and the right precision. None of the others do.

[Last df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66umG.png)

Comment: I cannot reproduce this because I don't know `some_computation` or `data`

Comment: Sorry the computations are a long series of manipulating the data and then calculating correlations which I thought wouldn't be useful here.

Comment: @Arkansin try `df1 = df.copy()`

Comment: Nope that didn't fix it :/
Thanks though!